# Laravel Auth "Call to a member function getReminderToken() on null"

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

No idea why I'm getting this error...

```
Call to a member function getRememberToken() on null (View: /home/vagrant/temptools/resources/views/layouts/main.blade.php) (View: /home/vagrant/temptools/resources/views/layouts/main.blade.php)
```

I have an Auth::check() on that blade page

I'm using https://github.com/invisnik/laravel-steam-auth

Routes:

```
Route::get('login', 'AuthController@redirectToSteam')->name('login');
Route::get('login/handle', 'AuthController@handle')->name('login.handle');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
```

AuthController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Invisnik\LaravelSteamAuth\SteamAuth;
use App\User;
use Auth;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * The SteamAuth instance.
     *
     * @var SteamAuth
     */
    protected $steam;

    /**
     * The redirect URL.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectURL = '/';

    /**
     * AuthController constructor.
     * 
     * @param SteamAuth $steam
     */
    public function __construct(SteamAuth $steam)
    {
        $this->steam = $steam;
    }

    /**
     * Redirect the user to the authentication page
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector
     */
    public function redirectToSteam()
    {
        return $this->steam->redirect();
    }

    /**
     * Get user info and log in
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        if ($this->steam->validate()) {
            $info = $this->steam->getUserInfo();

            if (!is_null($info)) {
                $user = $this->findOrNewUser($info);

                Auth::login($user, true);

                return redirect($this->redirectURL); // redirect to site
            }
        }
        return $this->redirectToSteam();
    }

    /**
     * Getting user by info or created if not exists
     *
     * @param $info
     * @return User
     */
    protected function findOrNewUser($info)
    {
        $user = User::where('id', $info->steamID64)->first();

        if (!is_null($user)) {
            return $user;
        }

        return User::create([
            'name' => $info->personaname,
            'avatar' => $info->avatarfull,
            'id' => $info->steamID64
        ]);
    }
}
```

app/User:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'name', 'avatar',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

create_users_table migration:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigInteger('id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('avatar');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->primary('id');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Have deleted the password recovery migration.

I also get the error if I hit the logout path:

```
Call to a member function getRememberToken() on null
```

========

Looking into errors, the error seems to be in laravel/framework/sec/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php line 67

```
public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token)
{
        $model = $this->createModel();
        $model = $model->where($model->getAuthIdentifierName(), $identifier)->first();
        $rememberToken = $model->getRememberToken();
        return $model && $rememberToken && hash_equals($rememberToken, $token) ? $model : null;
    }
```

Still no idea how to fix it though

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this package uses Laravel Auth... How do you set unique ID for your users? Generally you should auto increment them... Don't forget that Laravel's auth is reliant on many conventions... Look at AuthenticatesUsers trait for a peek... but one of the fields required is email...

```
trait AuthenticatesUsers
{
     /**
     * Get the login username to be used by the controller.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function username()
    {
        return 'email';
    }
}
```

Take a look around the Auth structure, look at the default 'web' guard (look at auth.php in the config directory as a starting point... ).

---

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();   //Unique ID for login in laravel? The AuthenticatesUser trait uses email as username... 
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('avatar');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Go into this function parent:

```
public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token){
    $model = $this->createModel();
    $model = $model->where($model->getAuthIdentifierName(), $identifier)->first();
    $rememberToken = $model->getRememberToken();
    return $model && $rememberToken && hash_equals($rememberToken, $token) ? $model : null;
}
```

dump the model and $identifier,

create a model row with that identifier and it will fixed!